# How to take PRINT of content from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am using swift, i need to take print of a sheet which is opened in UIWebView.

```
    let url = webView.request?.url
    let stringurl = url?.absoluteString

    let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)

    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    printInfo.jobName = stringurl!

    pic.printInfo = printInfo
    pic.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()
    pic.showsPageRange = false

    pic.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

in `UIWebViewDelegate` in function `webViewDidFinishLoad` we need to "redirect" `window.print` function to our native function that will take care of print:

```
open func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "(function(){var originalPrintFn = window.print;window.print = function(){window.location = 'webViewPrintAction';}})();")
}
```

next step:

```
public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
   if request.url!.absoluteString.contains("webViewPrintAction") {
            printContent()
            return false
        }
   return true
}
```

and final step inmplement `printContent()` function:

```
private func printContent() {
   let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
   printInfo.jobName = webView.description
   printInfo.outputType = .general

   let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
   printController.printInfo = printInfo
   printController.printingItem = webView
   printController.present(animated: true)
}
```

And now when we will press `print` in webView (1st screenshot)  we will see iOS native dialog (2nd screenshot):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work.`printingItem` can only accept NSURL, NSData, UIImage, or ALAsset. It doesn't accept a UIView.

Comment: instead of `printController.printingItem = webView` should use `printController.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()`

Answer (score 0):

Draw the contents of the web view to a `UIImage` by creating an image context and then calling the `drawHierarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)` method on the web view.

You can then pass the resulting image as the `printingItem` to your print interaction controller.